# Sequence of integers program

Tags: visual-c++

A sequence of integers such as 1, 3, 5, 7, ... can be represented by a function that takes a nonnegative integer as paramater and returns the corresponding term of the sequence. For example, the sequence of odd numbers can be represented by the function

```
 int odd(int k) {return 2 * k + 1;}
```

Write an abstract class AbstractSeq that has a pure virtual member function

virtual int fun(int k) = 0;

as a stand-in for an actualsequence, and two member functions

```
void printSeq(int k, int m);

int sumSeq(int k, int m)
```

that are passed two integer paramaters k and m, where k < m. The function printSeq will print all the terms fun(k) through fun(m) of the sequence, and likewise, the function sumSeq will return the sum of those terms. Demonstrate your AbstractSeq class by creating subclasses that you use to sum the terms of at least two different sequences. Determine what kind of output best shows off the operation of these classes, and write a program that produces that kind of output.

Comment: This reads as a homework question that's been copied and pasted. It'd be more useful if you showed us how far you've got and where you're stuck.